# How to add custom code to share intent

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've implemented the rather out-of-box ShareActionProvider setup in a test app I'm experimenting with (using the support.v7.widget version). While it works fine, I want to run a little custom code - in this case just an internal stat counter sort of function to record how many times "share" was tapped on a particular item. (I understand from other answers there isn't a reliable way to determine the success of the share intent, let alone to where it was shared, so this seems like a last resort already.) The onOptionsItemSelected method does not seem to run in this situation.

This is the relevant part of my menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:title="Share via"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And the full onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "FOO");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "FOO");

    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

    return true;
}
```

On other actionbar items I would typically do something like this in onOptionsItemSelected, but it doesn't ever get called upon in this situation...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Integer id = item.getItemId();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "id = " + id);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "shareid = " + R.id.action_share);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Why won't this happen?");

    if (id.equals(R.id.action_share)) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Why won't this happen? 2");
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Edit:** I think the conversation thus far is barking up the wrong tree, as when I click the share icon *nothing* in the above (revised) onOptionsItemSelected is logged (log level verbose), though the sharing list pops up, which seems to confirm my theory that the ShareActionProvider isn't calling this method at all.

**Edit 2:** I've now modified the onCreateMenuOptions to look exactly as it does [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) with the exception of using MenuItemCompat - you can see the full source of the activity [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/88bd10559bdb99a59595). Still, nothing is logged in onOptionsItemSelected. I further experimented in adding another item to the same menu that does nothing but log a message when selected, and that works just fine.

Comment: You could alternatively use `SharedPreferences` in order to store something info even after exiting your app. You can use a counter for the share button and store the info onto preferences.
FYI: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: @zIronManBox I do indeed want to save that count to SharedPreferences, but I'm looking for where I can place that code to increment the count since the typical selected action doesn't seem to fire in this situation.

Comment: Try something like this inside `switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_share:
         // your code;
        break;
}`

Comment: I'm already doing this (using an if instead of a switch/case, since there's only one). I've expanded my question to include the whole onOpionsItemSelected function.

Comment: Then `==` might be the issue, its objects I believe try `equals()`

Comment: Can you please post the exact code of onCreateOptionsMenu and of the if statement in onOptionsItemSelected?

Comment: do you got it fixed?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan not working as yet. The problem is specific to the share item and any other items work as expected.

Comment: could you able to see the share intent options ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan added back the intent options. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/88bd10559bdb99a59595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed with all but total certainty that onMenuItemSelected is never called on ShareActionProvider menu items:

- The googlesamples [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActionBarCompat-ShareActionProvider/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/actionbarcompat/shareactionprovider/MainActivity.java) of ShareActionProvider doesn't even implement the method
- This *[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187151/how-to-detect-when-user-selects-menu-item-with-shareactionprovider)* (not the answer) - clearly not authoritative in itself but the answers here led me further to what I needed to do.

I ended up resolving my problem by adding an OnShareTargetSelectedListener to my ShareActionProvider in onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    setShareIntent(getShareIntent());

    // THESE ARE THE ANSWER BITS
    mShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(
            new ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider, Intent intent) {
                    // report the share event
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Shared!");

                    // return value is ignored, so false is fine
                    return false;
                }
            });

    // Return true to display menu
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the

```
Log.wtf("MainActivity", "Why won't this happen?");
```

is not printed on your console then note that [the "wtf" are logged at level ASSERT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#wtf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) so check your console log level. Another hint would be to also log the id

```
int id = item.getItemId();
```

and check if it matches the:

```
R.id.action_share
```

integer value.

If your code does not get at onOptionsItemSelected at all then probably the

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "FOO");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "FOO");

mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
```

is in the wrong place (onCreateOptionsMenu). Try removing it and see if onOptionsItemSelected gets called, if yes then add the code to onOptionsItemSelected inside your if statement. Please check [ShareProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html) sample on http://developer.android.com

**EDIT 2:**
Well it seems that if a menuItem has been set with an ActionProvider (in your case the ShareActionProvider) then the onOptionsItemSelected for this menuItem is not called. You can test this if you remove from your menu.xml the line:

```
app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
```

(Remember to remove any code referencing ShareActionProvider in your class else null object exceptions will rise.

Supposedly there is way to override this behavior by reading about [ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ActionProvider.html#onPerformDefaultAction()) but I could not write a sample to show this behavior.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and confirmed per revised question that onOptionsItemSelected is not being called when share is selected. So if I can find the place where I can successfully log the information you suggested that may well answer my question.